# Steaming LLM response with flask

Tags: python, flask, streaming, large-language-model

I am trying to create a flask based api to stream the response from a local LLM model.
I am trying to achieve it making use of the callbacks function of langchain.
But cannout understand why the **stdout(token)** streaming works while the **yield(token)** does not work.
Below is the sample code :

```
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackHandler
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

class MyCustomHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    async def  on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs: Any) :
        """Run on new LLM token. Only available when streaming is enabled."""
        #sys.stdout.write(token)
        yield f"{token}"
        #sys.stdout.flush()



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/<query>')
def hello_world(query):
    handler = MyCustomHandler()
    model_id = 'TheBloke/Mistral-7B-codealpaca-lora-GGUF'
    config = {'temperature':0.00, 'context_length':4000,} 
    llm = CTransformers(model=model_id, 
                        model_type='mistral',
                        config=config,
                        #verbose=True,
                        stream=True,
                        callbacks=[handler]
                        )

    prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template("you are an assistant answer the following : {query}")
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=prompt)

    return Response(chain.run(query))
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(port = 8000)
```

I am making a call to the flask server using the following code :

```
import requests

with requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/', stream=True) as resp:
    print(resp.text)
```

Any suggestion and recommendations is much appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Expecting a streaming response via an API call.

Comment: Now that you have async function, why not `FastAPI`?

Comment: To use use async functionality within your route you will have to use the async keyword when you define your route function. See flask documentation for details https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/async-await/.

Comment: @EAW I have tried that but the result is the same.